'Tooltip' cannot be used as a JSX component - react-tooltip error
Getting this error when trying to use react-tooltip on NextJS with server side rendering despite importing Tooltip with import { Tooltip } from 'react-tooltip' and having run npm install @types/react-tooltip
'Tooltip' cannot be used as a JSX component

This is related to using server side rendering in NextJS 13+. As a workaround, create a new component to wrap the tooltip export in a client component -
// app/components/ReactTooltip.tsx
'use client'

export { Tooltip } from 'react-tooltip'

then instead of importing Tooltip directly from react-tooltip, import Tooltip from this component -
import { Tooltip } from 'components/ReactTooltip'
source: https://react-tooltip.com/docs/troubleshooting
